# How to calculate the Fermi wave vector knowing the number of conduction electrons per atom

Tags: solid-state-physics

For a periodic lattice, with lattice constant $a$ and effective electron mass $m$, how would I estimate the Fermi wave vector knowing only that the number of conduction electrons per atom is 3?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the Fermi wave vector? Do you mean the Fermi surface? Even then this question doesn't make much sense. Please clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: Lazy homework question. The size of the Fermi vector in a free electron gas depends on the number of electrons per volume.